# jQuery appear plugin - adding if to statement

Tags: jquery

I'm a noob in jQuery and I'm trying to add a class to a div when I scroll down to a specific section. I found the jQuery appear plugin (https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) that helps me do just that, but I'm trying to state an if in the middle of it without any success.

My code is as follows:

```
$('#section').appear();
$('#section').on('appear', function() {
  $('.component').addClass('myclass');
});
```

That works just fine, but I can't figure out how to remove the class if I scroll up and the section is no longer visible. I figure that what would work is something like if section appear = true, then addClass, else removeClass, but I don't know how to write it down.

In the plugin github page there is also the disappear option, but I couldn't get that to work at all.

I know the answer is most likely very simple but like I said I'm a noob and I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Form the documentation:

> Also this plugin provides custom jQuery filter for manual checking element appearance.

```
$('someselector').is(':appeared')
```

So you need to test this condition to be false on scroll:

```
$(window).on("scroll",function(){
  if( !$("#section").is(':appeared') ){
    $(".component").removeClass("myclass");
  }
});
```

The `!` in front is a negation operator...

---

**EDIT**

Also from the documentation... Looks like there is a `dissapear` event...

```
$('someselector').on('disappear', function(event, $all_disappeared_elements) {
  // this element is now outside browser viewport
});
```

You definitely should read the documentation carefully.
From my 20 seconds reading it... It looks complete.